# can a cell evolve into a different species in the lab?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, molecular-evolution

A friend of mine does not believe in evolution. He claimed that we can not as humans observe a single cell evolving into a different cell. Is that possible to be observed in the lab?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First it is worth noting individuals don't evolve, populations evolve.

We can observe cells giving rise to different cells, the long term E.coli experiment is a famous and ongoing example, not only can evolution be observed but because sample cells from the population are taken and frozen periodically, it can be repeated! that is you can observe a change then set up the same line of cells under the same or under different conditions to see if the changes are different. In some cases even the exact same mutations can be observed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._coli_long-term_evolution_experiment

http://myxo.css.msu.edu/ecoli/

https://www.pnas.org/content/105/23/7899

Comment: +1 Moreover, building devices to observe evolutionary changes has become nearly "popular mechanics" level activity: [morbidostat](https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2013.021)